# How do I get the Remote IP address in Blazor version 8

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In Blazor versions 6/7 I can get the remote IP address in _Host.cshtml with:

```
@inject ILogger<Pages__Host> Logger
RemoteIp = HttpContext.GetRemoteIpAddress(Logger);
```

But this does not work in App.razor in version 8. So how can I get this in version 8?

Comment: Have you considered getting it in pre-render and then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#persist-prerendered-state

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis That link is for version 7 (and earlier) and it's built around using _Host.cshtml which is gone in version 8. Am I missing something? I'd also like to get it once per session/circuit and not have that overhead on every page rendered in the session. TIA

Comment: The ip address can be caught in the root component (App.razor) via the new (v8) cascading parameter HttpContext. The root component is the only place where the HttpContext is safely available. You may then propagate it via a cascading parameter of your own (only available during prerendering) and/or PersistentComponentState.

Comment: @PaulDurant Thank you. Please post as an answer and I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Yes, see my posted answer that also does as PaulDurant suggests.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis When I was last on this question your answer was deleted. I assumed you did that for a good reason and therefore didn't read it. Sorry.

Comment: As I added the answer I saw a couple of improvements in the logic so made the mods without actually testing them.  After adding the answer and testing, I discovered a flaw in my logic, so I temporarily deleted it until I fixed the logic.  I was going to just do a comment as Paul did, but as I hadn't actually used *PersistentComponentState* before, I'd write a full working example.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis So I had "perfect" timing when I was checking this. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple service:

```cs
public class IPAddressService
{
    public const string TokenName = "IPAddress";

    public string RemoteIpAddress { get; set; } = "Not Set";
}
```

Register Services:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPAddressService>();
```

Get the IpAddress and persist it in `App.razor`

```cs
@implements IDisposable
@using SO78174146.Components.Pages
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SO78174146.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

@code{
    [CascadingParameter] HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }
    [Inject] public PersistentComponentState ApplicationState { get; set; } = default!;

    private PersistingComponentStateSubscription? _persistingSubscription;
    private bool _subsequentRender;
    private string RemoteIpAddress = "Not Set";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.RemoteIpAddress = this.HttpContext?.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString() ?? "Not Set";
        _persistingSubscription = ApplicationState.RegisterOnPersisting(this.PersistData);
    }

    public Task PersistData()
    {
        this.ApplicationState.PersistAsJson<string>(IPAddressService.TokenName, this.RemoteIpAddress);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        _persistingSubscription?.Dispose();
    }

}
```

A Component to get the persisted IPAddress using *Persisting Component State*.

```cs
public class IPAddressGrabber : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] public IPAddressService IPAddressService { get; set; } = default!;
    [Inject] public PersistentComponentState ApplicationState { get; set; } = default!;

    private bool _subsequentRender;
    private const string TokenName = "IPAddress";
    private string RemoteIpAddress = "Not Set";

    // Short circuit all the lifecycle stuff - we don't need it
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        if (_subsequentRender)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        // if not prerender, try and get the persisted value
        if (this.ApplicationState.TryTakeFromJson<string>(IPAddressService.TokenName, out var address))
        {
            this.RemoteIpAddress = address ?? "Not Set";
            this.IPAddressService.RemoteIpAddress = this.RemoteIpAddress;
        }

        _subsequentRender = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Add it to `Routes`

```cs
<IPAddressGrabber />

<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

Demo Page:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject IPAddressService IpAddressService
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="bg-dark text-white" m-2 p-2>
    <pre>IpAddress: @(IpAddressService.RemoteIpAddress.ToString())</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried Paul's suggestion and added `[CascadingParameter] HttpContext HttpContext{ get; set; }` to App.razor.cs and that works. I then save it off in a scope level service I have for scope properties. Any reason to not just do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that doesn't work.   App is only pre-rendered and when you save the IP address, you're saving it to the *HttpRequest* scoped context, not the *SPA* scoped context.  Paul says you need to use *PersistentComponentState*.

Comment: Glad I asked on this and you explained. I have the code in App.razor.cs and it saves to the scoped service - but it's not the same service I get in my pages. Same for the `OnAfterRenderAsync` in it - never called. So I'll implement your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Can I put an `OnAfterRenderAsync` in that service too? I have several JavaScript calls I need to make per session (browser timezone, window width, etc.). And you use `SetParametersAsync` instead of `OnInitializedAsync` just because it comes first - correct? TIA

Comment: @PaulDurant -Did I see a comment about IHttpContextAccessor? Yes, it is discouraged because most people abuse it.  I've revamped the answer using your suggestion of accessing the !HttpContext` in `App`.

Comment: David.  See my revised answer.  Paul's comment in the question "The ip address can be caught in the root component (App.razor) via the new (v8) cascading parameter HttpContext" finally sank in over dinner, and triggered a revision.

Comment: Bad news - works on first page. But if I then do a hard refresh of then page, then on rebuilding the page App.razor is not called again. And IPAddressGrabber has nothing in the ApplicationState. Any suggestions? TIA

Comment: See my demo here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.PreRenderState - where it works.  What are you doing differently in the load sequence on the page where doing a hard refresh doesn't work?

Comment: I got it all working. I had one part wrong. PersistentComponentState is interesting, it carries across the different instances (or whatever you call it) for each of the event processing queues. Makes sense that it has to carry it as JSON. Anyways, as always, thanks.