# Why is OnInitializedAsync() called twice on a page reload

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Normally when a page is being created & rendered in Blazor version 8, RenderMode.InteractiveServer, `OnInitializedAsync()` is called once. But when I do a Reload on Chrome, it is called twice. And all child components in the page are called twice too.

Why is it being called twice? And what can I do to avoid reading from the database to populate the page twice? And very importantly, in a way that will call from the database at least once for any situation?

Every time I think I finally understand the rendering mode, I realize I have it wrong again. So InteractiveServer may call OnInitializedAsync() twice if pre-rendering is on. And I want that lightening fast initial render. And there is no way to know if a call is the pre-render or post-render call. Or possibly the only-render call.

To handle this I have seen three main approaches suggested:

1. Save the DB query to populate the page in a cache. Have the cache timeout in 15 seconds so it's basically only good for the pre (read from the DB) and post (read from the cache). That works. But, that means the pre-render call to OnInitializedAsync() may not return for several seconds. Is that ok?
2. Only do fast operations in OnInitializedAsync(), pre & post. Then read the DB and populate the page in OnAfterRenderAsync(true). But this means initializing as part of the rendering process. And then forcing a re-render of the page. Possibly multiple re-renders as I populate multiple components in a page. Is this ok?
3. Use `[CascadingParameter] HttpContext? == null` to determine if it's the pre-render.
4. Or is there another approach?

Comment: Is that specific to Chrome?

Comment: I think MrC, Logarr, and Rena all give useful different approaches to this question. I suggest you read all three. I would accept all three as answers if SO allowed but as they don't, I accepted MrC's answer as that's the approach I'm taking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does answer this question - [Persist prerendered state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0#persist-prerendered-state). So the suggested approach from Microsoft is read from the DB on the pre-render `OnInitializedAsync`, save that, and then reuse it for the subsequent `OnInitializedAsync` call.

With that said, the solutions listed here by MrC, Logarr, and Rena are all valid approaches that work.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this happens because of pre-rendering. To answer the other questions that naturally come from this situation:

- There is no way to know inside of `OnInitializedAsync()` whether or not this is the first time, or the second time.
- Pre-rendering causes two calls to it because you're actually creating two separate instances of the component/page when you navigate to it. The first one is to get the *bare minimum* of page content ready to give to the client so that they're not sitting on a blank page while more expensive operations run.
- When pre-rendering you have to switch your approach to using `OnAfterRenderAsync()` to do your heavy lifting.

When you aren't pre-rendering you can take the time to load the page and `OnInitializedAsync()` gets called once like a normal constructor would. That means you can do all your setup in there. Load initial data, set properties on child components, etc. Anything you only want to happen **once** when the page is first instantiated goes there.

But pre-rendering gives you two! The first one is very short lived. It gets initialized (constructed) and sent out to the client to occupy their screen while the app creates the second instance. The second instance is the one that lives the remainder of the time they're on the page. The first one gets disposed.

So where do you do your "I only want to do this once" work? In `OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)`. *This* method becomes your real "only once" location. Specifically when `firstRender` is true. The load process looks like this:

1. Navigate to page.
2. `OnInitializedAsync()` called. In it you set placeholder text, set loading flags to true, etc. **DO NOT DO EXPENSIVE OPERATIONS HERE!** Only do what is necessary to have a valid page displayed to the user.
3. Page is rendered and sent to browser.
4. `OnInitializedAsync()` is called again, this time for the instance of the component that will live the rest of the time.
5. `OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)` is called, and `firstRender` is true. In it you have a branch that is only hit when `firstRender` is true. This is where you do your initial data loading. Anything expensive that you don't want to hold up the page loading for the user that you would normally put in `OnInitializedAsync()` goes here. Load that data, set that loading flag to false, calculate one million decimals of pi, whatever.
6. The RenderTree gets updated and pushed out to the client with all that fully loaded data you've been gathering behind the scenes.
7. The user interacts with something on the page causing a render event to happen.
8. Events fire, methods are called, etc. and then...
9. `OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)` is called, and `firstRender` is **false**. Now you should only be doing the things that you want happening every single render.

I don't fully understand why there are two whole instances of the page that get created rather than just doing a shortcut to rendering the first time around, but whatever. I'm no frontend framework designer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail. This has me in a quandary because @MrCakaShaunCurtis  stresses that we should treat initialization distinct from rendering and his arguments for that are persuasive. But you make a persuasive argument in favor of populating the data after it has rendered. Which then causes a re-render.

Comment: I assume that the re-rendering that happens in this situation is the same as when a user clicks a dropdown in that only the diff of the DOM gets sent to the client rather than the entire thing again. That's a cheap expense in order to ensure a rendered page for the user as fast as possible (SEO anyone?). How do you interpret their use of the terms "initialization" and "rendering"?

Comment: I agree that in the pre-render environment, running code in `OnAfterRender` you don't want run in pre-render mode seems like a good idea.  But that's only because it happens to be there: it wasn't designed for that purpose, and there are issues in using it for that purpose.  What we really need is a different base component that provides a pre-render handle for us to use.

Comment: Your event sequence is only one of several possible. One key issue in using `OnAfterRender{Async}` for loading data is it's actually a UI event. There's no guarantee when it's executed, and therefore the state of the component when it is. The Blazor Synchronisation Context favours posted code over UI event code, so the first `OnAfterRender{Async}` may run during a yield in `OnInitializedAsync/OnParametersSetAsync` [if the queue is empty] or not until the lifecycle methods have completed [if it's busy]. The component state is likely to have changed between those two positions.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis The documentation and my experience has shown that the actions that cause `OnInitializedAsync()` to trigger a render are well defined. And that it's the same for both the pre-render and the standard render. Are there things beyond what the documentation lists that cause a render?

Comment: My point was not about `OnInitializedAsync()`, but about when `OnAfterRender{Async}` is actually executed by the *Synchronisation Context*.  I need to go and find some code I wrote a while ago to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: See this gist - https://gist.github.com/ShaunCurtis/f24cdf8fadad3c96133ecccc18a4052b

Answer (score 1):

As the [document](https://Hi%20@DavidThielen,%20the%20official%20document%20is%20said%20very%20clear,%20If%20the%20OnInitialized%7BAsync%7D%20lifecycle%20method%20for%20initializing%20the%20component%20is%20present,%20the%20method%20is%20executed%20twice:1.When%20the%20component%20is%20prerendered%20statically.2.After%20the%20server%20connection%20has%20been%20established.%20Reference:%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering) said:

> If the OnInitialized{Async} lifecycle method for initializing the
> component is present, the method is executed twice:
>
> When the component is prerendered statically.
>
> After the server connection has been established.

It is called twice, as you are using pre-rendering. Because by default the interactive server model is pre-rendering. You need go to `App.razor` and manually set the render mode prerender false like below:

```
<Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender:false)" />
```

Comment: I'm confused. First off, my question is about `OnInitializedAsync()`, not `OnAfterRenderAsync()`. So why is pre-render affecting initialization? Second, when I navigate to another page, `OnInitializedAsync()` is called once. So why sometimes twice? TIA

Comment: And very important - is there a way to determine if the call is pre-render or post-render? Because I only want to read the DB to populate the page once (the post-render call). Again, TIA.

Comment: By default the interactive server mode is pre-rendering.

Comment: Hi @DavidThielen, the official document is said very clear, If the OnInitialized{Async} lifecycle method for initializing the component is present, the method is executed twice:1.When the component is prerendered statically.2.After the server connection has been established. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering

Comment: The link you provided suggests that I call the DB from `OnInitializedAsync()`, and then cache that result (for say 10 seconds) to then return the cached value on the second `OnInitializedAsync()` call. That will work but it means `OnInitializedAsync()` can not complete for 2 seconds during the pre-render. Won't that be a problem?

Comment: Hi @DavidThielen, Each option contains it own advantage and disadvantage. Using a cache to temporarily store database query results can be a useful strategy to prevent having to query the database multiple times in quick succession. It reduces the load on the database but initial visit might still be a little slower due to database operations.For your second option, very fast initial render because no heavy operations are performed in `OnInitializedAsync()` but the user might see a flash of loading content or incomplete content, which can be perceived as jarring.

Comment: No matter which approach to use will depend on your specific application requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> And there is no way to know if a call is the pre-render or post-render call.

Look at this code which detects the presence of the cascading `HttpContext`.  It only exists when the component is being pre-rendered.  I've used a simple `CascadingValue` to pass the state to all sub-components.

```cs
public record PreRenderState(bool IsPreRender);
```

```cs
// CascadingPreRenderState.razor

<CascadingValue Value="_preRenderState" IsFixed>
        @this.ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter] HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }

    private PreRenderState _preRenderState = new(false);

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _preRenderState = new(this.HttpContext is not null);
    }
}
```

```cs
// Routes.razor
<CascadingPreRenderState>

        <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
                <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
            </Found>
        </Router>

</CascadingPreRenderState>
```

You can then choose to display what you want on pre-render.  You can display a simple *Loading* page in `Routes` or handle it on a page by page basis.

Here's an example:

```cs
@page "/weather"

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

@if (this.preRenderState.IsPreRender)
{
    <p><em>Pre-Rendering...</em></p>
    return;
}

@if (forecasts != null)
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private PreRenderState preRenderState { get; set; } = new(false);
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (this.preRenderState.IsPreRender)
            return;

        // Simulate asynchronous loading to demonstrate a loading indicator
        await Task.Delay(500);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        }).ToArray();
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}
```

Comment: I respect you and appreciate your answers so I feel bad saying this. But it turns out [Microsoft does have a suggested approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0#persist-prerendered-state) to this question. So I've answered it below. If I've missed something on that, please let me know. Otherwise I'll select my answer. sorry - dave

Comment: NP - it's your question.  If you check back I used the PersistentComponentState in the answer to your question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78174146/how-do-i-get-the-remote-ip-address-in-blazor-version-8/78176451#78176451.   The best approach depends on the data you want to persist.  If your page gets a complex set of data then you have rather a lot of work to do to get it, persist it and then retrieve it.   Serialization/Deserialization is relatively costly.  And you need to do it for every page that might get F5 refreshed.

Comment: As I often think (but don't often type), it's your funeral! ;-)

Comment: Thank you and that's another good point against PersistentComponentState. I think MemoryCache might be better - [as I discuss here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78188326/is-there-any-advantage-to-persistentcomponentstate-over-memorycache). And I've implemented your solution above as I will likely find cases where that works best. Again, thanks

Comment: Per the "it's my funeral", yeah I feel often that learning Blazor is a constant 3 steps forward, 2 steps back. But my time on the Win95 project (I was a senior dev on the core team) really brought home to me the value of using the API as suggested. We faced so many constraints from applications that used the Win 3.1 API totally wrong - but they had market share and so we couldn't break them.

Comment: And... I'm already using your approach half the time (and caching the other half). I don't know where I'll end up as I'm still playing with things and seeing how they work, but yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Disable prerendering or use if(firstRender) in OnAfterRenderAsync.