# Is there any advantage to PersistentComponentState over MemoryCache?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

For Blazor `InteractiveServer` render mode, [the Microsoft documentation suggest that on the pre-render call I (and you) read the needed data for the page and save it to the PersistentComponentState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0#persist-prerendered-state). Then on the 2nd call to `OnInitializeAsync`, read from the PersistentComponentState to populate the page.

Why not use `MemoryCache`? Is there any downside to doing so? [Reading the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.persistentcomponentstate?view=aspnetcore-8.0) it looks like this is an app global data store, not a per circuit store. So I think `MemoryCache` is basically the same thing.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think your (now deleted) answer is very good. Please undelete it so I can select it as the answer.

Comment: Nah, I will leave it hidden. I'm not so sure about the usage with Wasm. Haven't really used or studied the PersistentComponentState yet.

Comment: @HenkHolterman ok. But my (just learning) with it so far bears out what you wrote. I'm InteractiveServer though, not WASM. And that PersistentComponentState persists through all the initialization and render modes/stages from what I've tested. thanks